# Windows power shell and gcloud commands

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, ssh, command-line-arguments, remote-access

I'm trying to move to windows PowerShell instead of cmd
One of the commands I run often is for connecting to GCP compute engines using ssh and binding the machine's ports to my local machine.
I use the following template (taken from GCP's docs):

```
gcloud compute ssh VM_NAME --project PROJECT_ID --zone ZONE -- -L LOCAL_PORT:localhost:REMOTE_PORT -- -L LOCAL_PORT:localhost:REMOTE_PORT
```

This works great when using cmd but when I try and run it in PowerShell I get the following error:

```
(gcloud.compute.ssh) unrecognized arguments:
  -L
  8010:localhost:8888
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try using the [stop parsing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token), that is, `gcloud computer ssh VM_NAME --%  --project...` to make sure Powershell doesn't try to be smart about the parameters.

Comment: @vonPryz didn't work, I get the following - `(gcloud.compute.ssh) unrecognized arguments: --%`

Comment: That looks like you are passing the command to another a command processor than Powershell. You are running `gcloud` in Powershell? Try then  `gcloud --% compute ssh...`.

Comment: Please provide more details. Your local machine is Windows and you want to connect via SSH on GCP VM with which OS? Did you configure firewall on your local machine and GCP firewall? Do you want to connect to [Windows VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/how-to#connecting-to-windows-vm-instances) or [Linux VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/how-to#connecting-to-linux-vm-instances)?

Comment: @vonPryz Thanks but that didn't solve it either =/

Comment: @Pjoter I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the remote machine itself. As I said, the same command works when running in cmd... This is some issue with the parsing
In any case I'm on windows 10 trying to connect to Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I assume you already installed [gcloud ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows) on windows. What about connecting using `gcloud compute ssh VM_NAME --project PROJECT_ID --zone ZONE` without L param?

Comment: it works without the L param, but I need them for binding relevant ports

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve using Powershell connecting to VM? You want to ssh from PS to VM and then do something on that Linux VM? Is there anything specific why it need to be done via PS? You cannot do it via Putty as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#windows-putty) Powershell can manage GCP resources but IMO it's quite limited. [Here](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/) you can find powershell specific commands.